# Building a JSON string using javascript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, stringify

I'm using the $.post() function from jQuery to make a Ajax call with a JSON string. The call looks like this:

```
$.post(
    urlVar,
    jsonVar,
    function(data){
        //do stuff
    },
    'json'
)
.complete(function(){
    //do other stuff
});
```

To create *jsonVar* I'm using this code

```
var1 = {};
var1.id = fooId;
var1.amount = fooAmount;
var1.zoom = fooZoom;
jsonVar = JSON.stringify(var1);
```

To make the call work, *jsonVar* should look like this

```
{id:fooId, amount:fooAmount, zoom:fooZoom}
```

but it looks like this

```
{"id":fooId, "amount":fooAmount, "zoom":fooZoom}
```

Now my code will not work, because of the double quotes. I couldn't figure out how to get rid of those. Can anyone help me out?

IMPORTANT:

the code does work if I put the `$.post()` function like this:

```
$.post(
    urlVar,
    {id: fooId, amount: fooAmount, zoom: fooZoom},
    function(data){
        //do stuff
    },
    'json'
)
.complete(function(){
    //do other stuff
});
```

Comment: I'd interject that there might be something fundamentally wrong with the receiving end of the AJAX call, because that second JSON string is legal JSON syntax. In fact, I think that's actually standard (over the no-quotation-mark version).

Comment: You example appears to be flawed in that "zoom" is never a part of var1 but is actually a part of var2.

Comment: i had the same problem in different browsers. it worked after qouting the values in the json-string. like:
{"id":"fooId", "amount":"fooAmount", "zoom":"fooZoom"}

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss My bad, that was a typo.

Comment: @some_coder ~ `{ "id" : fooId }` and `{ id : fooId }` are *virtually* the same, but `{ "id" : "fooId" }` is not. That latter one uses a string value, the others reference the `fooId` variable's value.

Comment: @RichardNeillagen, you are right, but i thought JSON.stringify should handle this.

Comment: @RichardNeilIlagan. If you look at the edit I made to my question, you'll see why I think it has gone wrong because of the double quotes.

Comment: @some_coder ~ in terms of why that's an error, no it doesn't. It's the difference between `x.id = fooId;` and `x.id = "fooId";` when using it like `JSON.stringify(x);`.

Comment: @LuudJacobs ~ if that works, then passing `var1` directly into the AJAX call should work as well. Have you given that a try?

Answer (score 1):

The [JSON specification](http://www.json.org/) states that the keys must have double-quotes.

What do you mean your code won't work because of double quotes?  Parse the JSON back into an object using **JSON.parse**; which is built-in to many modern browsers or you can shim it using the [json2](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/) library.

Answer (score 0):

Given this code:

```
var fooId = 'foodyfood';
var fooAmount = 10.20;
var fooZoom = 'zoomer';
var var2 = {};

var var1 = {}; 
var1.id = fooId; 
var1.amount = fooAmount; 
var2.zoom = fooZoom; 
jsonVar = JSON.stringify(var1); 
$('#showme').text(jsonVar);
```

the value shown in the showme would be:

```
{"id":"foodyfood","amount":10.2}
```

so your example appears to be flawed and actually is not JSON standard which specifies the double quotes.

EDIT: now your use of the post is the equivelent of:

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: url,
  data: data,
  success: success,
  dataType: dataType
});
```

except that it handles the object as objects in your second example after your edit.

see the example in the documentation here: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

with this form:

```
$.post("test.php", { name: "John", time: "2pm" },   function(data) {
     alert("Data Loaded: " + data);   
});
```

so if you have:

```
var mytest =  { name: "John", time: "2pm" };
```

it becomes: on the stringify

```
{"name":"John","time":"2pm"}
```

see working example here:http://jsfiddle.net/v4NHv/

Comment: one note, if you need a parameter to pass you might use `$.param(var1);` form which creates: id=foodyfood&amount=10.2

Answer (score 0):

Change the `post` call like this

```
$.post(
    urlVar,
    {var1:jsonVar},
    function(data){
      //do stuff
   },
   'json'
)
.complete(function(){
   //do other stuff
});
```

And then of course you will need to make a little tweek to your receiving app